# Converting CVImageBuffer to YUV420 object

Tags: ios, opencv, avfoundation

I want to maintain YUV420 format of the streaming video from the camera to avoid penalties in conversion to grayscale, but I also want to keep the color component. The ultimate goal is processing with a computer vision library like OpenCV. While I might ultimately choose BGRA, I still want to be able to test a working solution with YUV. So how can I convert a CVImageBuffer with pixel format `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange` into a single chunk of memory?

Solutions rejected:

- CIImage is super convenient, but doesn't allow rendering to a bitmap in YUV format.
- cv::Mat pollutes your Obj-C code with C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### AVCaptureSessionDelegate

This will stuff the data into an NSObject containing the bytes depending on the specified pixel format. I went ahead and provided the ability to detect and malloc memory for either BGRA or YUV pixel formats. So this solution is perfect for testing the two.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    CVImageBufferRef videoImageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(videoImageBuffer, 0);

    void *baseAddress = NULL;
    NSUInteger totalBytes = 0;
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(videoImageBuffer);
    size_t height = 0;
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(videoImageBuffer);
    OSType pixelFormat = CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(videoImageBuffer);
    if (pixelFormat == kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange ||
        pixelFormat == kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange) {
        size_t planeCount = CVPixelBufferGetPlaneCount(videoImageBuffer);
        baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(videoImageBuffer, 0);

        for (int plane = 0; plane < planeCount; plane++) {
            size_t planeHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(videoImageBuffer, plane);
            size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(videoImageBuffer, plane);
            height += planeHeight;
            totalBytes += (int)planeHeight * (int)bytesPerRow;
        }
    } else if (pixelFormat == kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA) {
        baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(videoImageBuffer);
        height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(videoImageBuffer);
        size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(videoImageBuffer);
        totalBytes += (int)height * (int)bytesPerRow;
    }

    // Doesn't have to be an NSData object
    NSData *rawPixelData = [NSData dataWithBytes:baseAddress length:totalBytes];

    // Just a plain-ol-NSObject with the following properties
    NTNUVideoFrame *videoFrame = [[NTNUVideoFrame alloc] init];
    videoFrame.width = width;
    videoFrame.height = height;
    videoFrame.bytesPerRow = bytesPerRow;
    videoFrame.pixelFormat = pixelFormat; 
    // Alternatively if you switch rawPixelData to void *
    // videoFrame.rawPixelData = baseAddress;
    videoFrame.rawPixelData = rawPixelData;
    [self.delegate didUpdateVideoFrame:videoFrame];

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(videoImageBuffer, 0);
}
```

The only thing you need to remember is that you will need to `malloc` and `memcpy` the base address if you plan on switching threads, or dispatch_async and you don't use `NSData`. Once you unlock the base address the pixel data will no longer be valid.

```
void *rawPixelData = malloc(totalBytes);
memcpy(rawPixelData, baseAddress, totalBytes);
```

At which point you need to consider the problem of calling free on that block of memory when done.